# Pyinstaller, unix файл не открывается на другом mac

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Нужна помощь. Написал скрипт на пайтон 3.8, через библиотеку pyinstaller командой pyinstaller myscript.py -F создал unix файл на моем mac. Скрипт открывается через терминал и работает хорошо, но стоит переслать его на другой mac, то он не работает, точнее автоматически открывается через TextEdit, и если открыть через терминал, то не работает тоже. Подскажите какие-нибудь пути решения, возможно нужно обернуть файл в .app через другую библиотеку? Скрипт довольно простой, берет данные по API и записывает их в новый .csv

Comment: Вы передали исключительно исполняемый файл или всю папку созданную инсталлером?

Comment: Передал только исполняемый файл. Обернул его в unix файл через pyinstaller командой pyinstaller myscript.py -F. Флагом -F, как я понимаю, я объединил весь скрипт в один файл и он создался без каких-либо доп. файлов/директорий. На других устройствах с macOS файл не запускается.

Comment: Вы объединили то его но там по любому должно бить ещё 2(вроде)  папки создаться и без них скрипт не запуститься

Comment: Спасибо! Вижу, что еще создается папка build и файл имяскрипта.spec. Попробую передать вместе с ними